# Replace keys with values in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Newbie question in dictionaries.

I'm trying to replace keys with values without using `iteritems` like I've seen in some answers here.

I have 2 dictionaries. One with stuff in it and an empty one. I'd like to keep the first one as is, but print out the second one with the the keys and values replaced from the first one.

So for example:

`d1 = {1:"hello", 2 : 10, 3 : 100.0}`

The print of d2 will be `"hello":1, 10:2, 100.0:3`

This is my try:

```py
d1 = {1:"hello", 2 : 10, 3 : 100.0}
d2 = {}
for k in d1:
    d2[d1[k]] == d2[k]
print(d2)
```

I'm not quite sure where I'm wrong.

Comment: Why not with `.items` like this `{v:k for k,v in d1.items()}`?

Comment: Keep in mind not all values can be dictionary keys. What are you trying to achieve by doing this key/value swap?

Comment: in general seems like a bad idea, but replace `d2[d1[k]] == d2[k]` with `d2[d1[k]] == k`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code need slight altering to get it to work as intended:

```
d1 = {1:"hello", 2 : 10, 3 : 100.0}
d2 = {}
for k in d1.keys():
    d2[d1[k]] = k
print(d2) # {'hello': 1, 10: 2, 100.0: 3}
```

Keep in mind however that `values` in `dict` might repeat, while `keys` can not (must be unique), so if any value will appear more than once in `d1`, after such operation you will have fewer elements in `d2`.

Comment: Thanks! So all it took was to change the `d2[k]` to just `k` I guess

Answer (score 3):

try this code:

```
 d1 = {1:"hello", 2 : 10, 3 : 100.0} 

d2 = dict([(value, key) for key, value in d1.items()]) 

for i in d2: 
    print(i, " :  ", d2[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `.items()` :-

```
d1 = {1:"hello", 2 : 10, 3 : 100.0}
d2 = {}
for key, value in d1.items():
    d2[value] = key
print(d2)
```

I hope it may help you.